# Remove rows before consecutive zero values in time series Using R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series as a data frame as follows:

```
date          country      value       id
1/1/2020       A            .2         Cv
1/2/2020       A             0         Cv
1/3/2020       A             0         Cv 
.....         ...           ....       ...
2/10/2020      A              2        ...
2/11/2020      A              0        Cv
3/11/2020.     A              0        Cv
4/11/2020      A              0        Cv
5/11/2020      A              3        Cv
6/11/2020      A              4        Cv
7/11/2020      A              6        Cv
8/11/2020      A              7        Cv
```

I want to remove all values before the last sequence of zero that we have in the data frame:
I tried following code:

```
test <- ddply(df,.(id),function(x){
  temp_country_data <- ddply(x, .(country),function(y){
    temp_data <- data.frame(y) %>% arrange(date) %>% group_by("id","country") 
dat<-temp_data
    ToRemove <- apply(dat, 2, function(colmn) {
      row.zeros <- which(colmn == 0) # rows with zeros
      if(length(row.zeros) > 0) { # if we found any
        # which of them is the last double
        last.doubles <- max(which(diff(row.zeros) == 1))
        leftof.last.doubles <- "if"(length(last.doubles) > 0, # if double exists1:(row.zeros[last.doubles]-1), # all rows before
                                    NULL) # else nothing
        # remove rows with single zeros and all rows before double consecutive 
        unique(c(row.zeros, leftof.last.doubles)) }
      temp_data<-dat[-unlist(ToRemove),]
    temp_data = temp_data[,c("date", "id", "country", "value")]
    temp_data
  }, .parallel = T)
  temp_country_data
}, .progress = 'text')
```

However it removes only zero values which i do not want.
I want that output be like as follows: Also i want to interval 2 days after the final sequence of zeros:

```
7/11/2020      A              6        Cv
8/11/2020      A              7        Cv
```

......

Also I tried this but still I am not getting the result:

```
test3 <- ddply(df,.(id),function(x){
  temp_country_data <- ddply(x, .(country),function(y){
    temp_data <- data.frame(y) %>% arrange(date) %>% group_by("id","country") 
    temp_data<- temp_data%>% mutate(flag_0 = ifelse(value == 0,1,0),flag_0_cum = cumsum(flag_0)) %>% 
      filter(flag_0_cum == max(flag_0_cum)) %>% 
      filter(round(value,3) != 0) %>% 
      select(-flag_0 , -flag_0_cum) %>%
      slice(3:n())
    temp_data = temp_data[,c("date", "short_id", "country", "raw_de")]
    library(lubridate)
    
    temp_data <- temp_data %>% 
      group_by(country, id) %>%                          
      mutate(DATE = ymd(date), 
             day_flag = if_else(DATE == (lag(DATE) + days(1)), 1, 0))

temp_data<- temp_data %>% filter(!is.na(day_flag))
temp_data<- temp_data %>% 
  mutate(flag_0 = ifelse(day_flag == 0,1,0),
         flag_0_cum = cumsum(flag_0)) %>% 
  filter(flag_0_cum == max(flag_0_cum)) %>% 
  filter(day_flag != 0) %>% 
  select(-flag_0 , -flag_0_cum) %>%
  slice(3:n())

   temp_data
  }, .parallel = T)
  temp_country_data
}, .progress = 'text')
```

I have added another column into my dataframe to flag the consecutive rows as 1 and not consecutive as zero .

could you please let me know where is the problem.

Comment: Can you clarify how your desired output is related to the example data that you have posted? The dates in the output do not occur on the original data so it is unclear how to reach this result by only removing values...

Comment: I have revised the code and i updated the question. I want the rows after 0 values (final conequative zero).menas that i want the data from 5/11/2020 but i also want to shift it to another 2 more days which will be 7/11/2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to label the occurrence of zeros with a cumulative sum (each time a new zero occurs the label is increased by one) and keep only the last group which includes the last zero and all subsequent non-zero values. Then we can remove the zero itself and the first 2 rows:

```
library(dplyr) 

df <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-11-01"),to = as.Date("2020-11-08"), by = "day"),
                 country = "A",
                 value = c(2,0,0,0,3,4,6,7),
                 id = "Cv")

df %>% 
  mutate(flag_0 = ifelse(round(value, 4) == 0, 1, 0),
         flag_0_cum = cumsum(flag_0)) %>% 
  filter(flag_0_cum == max(flag_0_cum)) %>% 
  filter(round(value, 4) != 0) %>% 
  select(-flag_0 , -flag_0_cum) %>%
  slice(3:n())
```

Comment: just one more question the value is not 0 it is 0.0004 so how I filter based on decimal 4 decimal i put round(value,4)!=0

Comment: Yes, that is possible. I adjusted the code to do that.

Comment: but the only problem is that when i round it some values such as 0.03 will not be round to 0 and then some uncosecutive days will be included could you help me to solve that problem as well.

Comment: So what is the threshold that you would want to use? In other word, what is the largest number that should still be treated as a zero? The 0.03 problem could be solved by rounding to one decimal instead of 3, but not sure if that is what you want...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `diff` to identify zeroes and `cumsum` to create a new index `ix`. Then exclude zero rows and apply `head` with value `2` in a `by` to get every first two rows after a zero. Finally `rbind`.

```
DF1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(DF, ix=cumsum(c(-1, diff(DF$value == 0)) %in% 1)))
DF1 <- DF1[DF1$value != 0, ]
res <- do.call(rbind, by(DF1, DF1$ix, head, 2))
head(res)
#           date country value id ix
# 0   2020-01-01       A   3.0 Cv  0
# 1.3 2020-01-03       A   3.0 Cv  1
# 1.4 2020-01-04       A   2.0 Cv  1
# 2.6 2020-01-06       A   3.0 Cv  2
# 2.7 2020-01-07       A   0.2 Cv  2
# 3   2020-01-10       A   4.0 Cv  3
```

---

*Data:*

```
DF <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18262, 18263, 18264, 18265, 
18266, 18267, 18268, 18269, 18270, 18271, 18272, 18273, 18274, 
18275, 18276, 18277, 18278, 18279, 18280, 18281, 18282, 18283, 
18284, 18285, 18286, 18287, 18288, 18289, 18290, 18291, 18292, 
18293, 18294, 18295, 18296, 18297, 18298, 18299, 18300, 18301, 
18302, 18303, 18304, 18305, 18306, 18307, 18308, 18309, 18310, 
18311, 18312, 18313, 18314, 18315, 18316, 18317, 18318, 18319, 
18320, 18321, 18322, 18323, 18324, 18325, 18326, 18327, 18328, 
18329, 18330, 18331, 18332, 18333, 18334, 18335, 18336, 18337, 
18338, 18339, 18340, 18341, 18342, 18343, 18344, 18345, 18346, 
18347, 18348, 18349, 18350, 18351, 18352, 18353, 18354, 18355, 
18356, 18357, 18358, 18359, 18360, 18361, 18362, 18363, 18364, 
18365, 18366, 18367, 18368, 18369, 18370, 18371, 18372, 18373, 
18374, 18375, 18376, 18377, 18378, 18379, 18380, 18381, 18382, 
18383, 18384, 18385, 18386, 18387, 18388, 18389, 18390, 18391, 
18392, 18393, 18394, 18395, 18396, 18397, 18398, 18399, 18400, 
18401, 18402, 18403, 18404, 18405, 18406, 18407, 18408, 18409, 
18410, 18411, 18412, 18413, 18414, 18415, 18416, 18417, 18418, 
18419, 18420, 18421, 18422, 18423, 18424, 18425, 18426, 18427, 
18428, 18429, 18430, 18431, 18432, 18433, 18434, 18435, 18436, 
18437, 18438, 18439, 18440, 18441, 18442, 18443, 18444, 18445, 
18446, 18447, 18448, 18449, 18450, 18451, 18452, 18453, 18454, 
18455, 18456, 18457, 18458, 18459, 18460, 18461, 18462, 18463, 
18464, 18465, 18466, 18467, 18468, 18469, 18470, 18471, 18472, 
18473, 18474, 18475, 18476, 18477, 18478, 18479, 18480, 18481, 
18482, 18483, 18484, 18485, 18486, 18487, 18488, 18489, 18490, 
18491, 18492, 18493, 18494, 18495, 18496, 18497, 18498, 18499, 
18500, 18501, 18502, 18503, 18504, 18505, 18506, 18507, 18508, 
18509, 18510, 18511, 18512, 18513, 18514, 18515, 18516, 18517, 
18518, 18519, 18520, 18521, 18522, 18523, 18524, 18525, 18526, 
18527, 18528, 18529, 18530, 18531, 18532, 18533, 18534, 18535, 
18536, 18537, 18538, 18539, 18540, 18541, 18542, 18543, 18544, 
18545, 18546, 18547, 18548, 18549, 18550, 18551, 18552, 18553, 
18554, 18555, 18556, 18557, 18558, 18559, 18560, 18561, 18562, 
18563, 18564, 18565, 18566, 18567, 18568, 18569, 18570, 18571, 
18572), class = "Date"), country = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), value = c(3, 0, 3, 2, 0, 
3, 0.2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 
3, 2, 0.2, 0, 2, 0.2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 
0.2, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0.2, 0.2, 
4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0.2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0.2, 3, 
0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 4, 3, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
2, 0.2, 4, 4, 2, 0.2, 0, 3, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0.2, 0, 
4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 3, 0, 0.2, 0, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 3, 4, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0.2, 3, 
2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 3, 0, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 
0.2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 
3, 0, 0.2, 0, 4, 4, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 3, 
3, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 3, 3, 
0, 0), id = c("Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", 
"Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv", "Cv")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-311L))
```

Comment: but I want to remove all the values before final consecutive zeros in the time series not only zero values

Comment: @user I'm afraid I don't understand, could you elaborate on "values before final consecutive zeros"?

Comment: I mean that in the data set that you provided the value in the the 250 index is the row that I need because before that we have two zero value and i do not need all the values before index 250

Comment: @user What about row 228 and 306?

Comment: you are right in this data set the value of 310 and 311 also is zero means that nothing should be selected from this dataset.